# Weird Template Strings behavior when creating Function object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, xss, template-strings

As I was fooling around with XSS challenges, I encountered weird behavior when creating Function object using template strings (`` instead of parentheses) in Javascript.

As i understand, when invoking

```js
alert`1`
```

It is essentially the same as

```js
alert(["1"])
```

as described [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings). I tested many cases and everywhere it worked that way - except when Function object is created using template strings.

When executing following code:

```js
var x = new Function`alert(1)`;
console.log(x.constructor);
```

instance of Object class is created with alert(1) function in it's constructor body so it's executed immediately.

If i understand correctly, it should be executed the same as

```js
var y = new Function(["alert(1)"]);
console.log(y.constructor)
```

and should just return Function object with alert(1) in body so it can called like this

```js
var y = new Function(["alert(1)"]);
y();
```

Where does this inconsistency come from or are template strings handled differently when creating objects?

Comment: you never save the intermediary Function, just the blank object `new` made

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the precedence of various pieces of the language grammar.

```
var x = new Function`alert(1)`;
```

is equivalent to

```
var x = new (Function`alert(1)`);
```

so what you're essentially doing is

```
var fn = Function`alert(1)`;
var x = new fn;
```

so you've created the function, and then called it with `new`.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now! Just wondering - why calling new on Function instance creates Object instance with constructor alert(1)? It is a bit unclear to me how that second line works.

Comment: You're essentially doing `var fn = function(){ alert(1); }; new fn;`. Does that clarify it?

Comment: Okay i got it. Didn't know that I can call something like `var x = new function(){this.val="property"; alert(1);}` and it will create new object using that function as constructor. Thanks for help.

Comment: (Hint, hint: just omit the `new`, it's not necessary to create a `Function`)